# Winning The game of Unstable Unicorns

Tags: unstable-unicorns

If a player has 7 unicorn cards and a magic card have they won or do they need to get rid of the magic card before they can win.

Answer (score 1):

They've won (besides, you can always just discard the magic card at the end of your turn anyhow).

Rules:

> The first person to successfully collect the required
> number of Unicorns in their Stable wins! Each Unicorn
> card counts for one Unicorn (unless otherwise stated).

> 2 – 5 Players: 7 Unicorns to win
> 6 – 8 Players: 6 Unicorns to win